# Building stack bar chart from objects array in flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts, bar-chart

I have a dynamic `ArrayCollection` that will contain an unknown number of objects of type `MyObj`:

```
class MyObj
{
   type:String
   value:long
}
```

each `MyObj` object has a different value of `type`.

How can I build a single stacked bar from this array where each section of the stacked bar represents an object of `MyObj` (represents a `type`) and its length is the `value`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    private var countries:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
        { Country: "Romania", Romanians: 0.7, Hungarians:0.2, Germans: 0.1 }]);
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Panel title="BarChart Control" layout="horizontal" color="0xffffff" borderAlpha="0.15" width="600" height="240"
     paddingTop="10" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="5" horizontalAlign="center">

     <mx:BarChart id="bar" height="100%" color="0x323232" type="stacked"
         showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{countries}">

        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="Country"/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>

        <mx:series>
            <mx:BarSeries yField="Country" xField="Romanians" displayName="Romanians"/>
            <mx:BarSeries yField="Country" xField="Hungarians" displayName="Hungarians"/>
            <mx:BarSeries yField="Country" xField="Germans" displayName="Germans"/>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:BarChart>

    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{bar}" color="0x323232"/>

</mx:Panel>
```